# How to create a Java desktop application?

Tags: java, swing, applet, desktop-application, japplet

I'm fairly new to Java, been taking it as a challenge course at my school, and I'm working on a chemistry-related "applet" (not sure if this is the right word for it) for one of my teachers. Right now, it runs just fine using Eclipse. I'm not sure how to make this a "clickable" application where I can open it from the desktop.

Keep in mind java is the only computer language I know! Thank you for your patience and I apologize for my inexperience.

P.S. I've extended `JApplet` with an `init()` and `paint(Graphics g)` method

Comment: Consider starting with [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Answer (score 1):

To make a true desktop application, you should not start by extending JApplet. Applets are meant to run as part of web pages. Eclipse will run them standalone to help you debug them.

You should consider creating a standalone Swing application. There are many tutorials out there to help you with that.

Eventually, once you have one, you can learn how to make it 'clickable', which varies rather considerably between operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

To make a desktop app., design the GUI in a `JPanel` then display it in a `JFrame`.  There is no need to extend either frame or panel in this case, just use instances of a frame and panels as needed.

To run as a desktop app. it requires an 'entry point', a class with a method..

```
public static void main(String[] args) { // ..
```

Applications with a `main` method can then be put in a Jar file, with a manifest identifying the main class.  That is known as a 'runnable Jar' and is the 'double click to run' type of thing you are thinking of.

On the other hand once you have that Jar, the best way to *distribute* it is via the net, and for that look to [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).